# mbtowc() function returns -1 for extended characters such as É(greater than decimal values 127)

Tags: linux, encoding, locale, special-characters, codepages

In LINUX system, I have set the locale as LC_ALL=en_US.cp1252

And in my program, I try to pass the char É(of hex code 0x90) 
1) to printf() - prints the character correctly 
2) to mbtowc() - returns -1(not accepting the character É) --> Any suggestions or idea about why it is like this?

Comment: Are you setting the locale correctly in your program? Needs a [mcve].

Comment: I have used export locale LC_ALL="en_US.cp1252" to set the locale in the Linux system thru terminal.. and verified the locale set thy "locale" command..

Comment: The sample which I execute : /* mbtowc example */
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <errno.h>

void printbuffer (const char* pt, size_t max)
{
  int length;
  wchar_t dest;

  int len = 0;
  len = mbtowc (NULL, NULL, 0);  

  while (max>0) {
    length = mbtowc(&dest,pt,max);
    if (length<1)
    {
        printf("\nErrno : %d", errno);
        break;
    }
    printf ("[%lc]",dest);
    pt+=length; max-=length;
  }
}

int main()
{
  const char chr = 0x90;
  printf("Char - %c", chr);

  printbuffer (&chr,sizeof(chr));

  return 0;
}

Comment: When I execute the above code - mbtowc() return -1 and the errno prints 84(which means "Illegal byte sequence") - Doesn't this function accepts extended chars like 0x90?